# FileProvider is queried by a client app with "_data" in projection

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider, android-fileprovider

I am implementing a [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html).

Its advantages over plain `ContentProvider` is greater security:

- secure sharing of files associated with an app by creating a `content://` `Uri` for a file instead of a `file:///` `Uri`
- a content URI allows to grant read and write access using temporary access permissions

So one of the points is that client app should not know the real file path to access the data.

For most of the client apps it's important to know the `human-friendly name of file` and/or `size of the file` before they start reading actual data. Those apps ask `FileProvider` about name/size via [query() method](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#query(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String)). The method expects only 2 options in `projection` param - [OpenableColumns](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/provider/OpenableColumns.html) (`_display_name`, `_size`).

And now the issue. Some client apps are passing `_data` into projection, expecting to get a real full path to the data. But returning a real file path would break the whole idea of using `FileProvider` for security reasons.

My question is 'Am I missing anything?'. Is it just some client apps are poorly written, so it's theirs problem that they crash because of not getting the file path?

Comment: you can use CursorWrapper and provied this column (like in commonsware's LegacyCompatCursorWrapper) ... but I would preffer "let them crash" way

Comment: `that they crash`. And you are telling that at the end of all talking? You should begin with that! Now why do they crash? What kind of info do you give? A null? You could only return the filename. Not the path. It's unclear what you actually do. You should name the crashinh apps too of course.

Comment: `client app should not know the real file path `. What does it matter? When the file is in your apps internal memory they cannot reach it. If your file is on external or removable media any other app can see it provided the external read permission is requested. If that app has external write permission requested it can also modify all files on external storage. So what is it that you want to protect?

Comment: So you are saying that a content provider works with a file uri an a file provider with a content uri? Funny.